# Unable to restore Ubuntu after reinstalling windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

One day I restarted my computer and found out that Ubuntu 12.04 would not load.  It would come to the dot prompt with no graphics. Windows 7 was loading OK though.

From Windows 7,  I navigated to grub folder and it was empty. Next time I restarted windows, I got the blue screen reporting system failure.  I tried to fix Windows with no luck, so I had to reinstall Windows using Factory Default options.

After reinstalling Windows I started Ubuntu from the 12.04 CD(try Ubuntu) and ran Boot Repair from the terminal.  The process was completed successfully. I restarted the computer, but I have the option to startup with windows only.

I am providing Boot Repair results http://paste.ubuntu.com/6635305/as recommended hoping to find a way to restore my Ubuntu.

Please help.

Thanks,

Felix

Answer (score 1):

Your boot-repair output shows that you don't have ANY Linux partition on your hard drive:

```
=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe48393f7

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      409599      203776    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          409600   595085311   297337856    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       595085312   624928767    14921728    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       624928768   625140399      105816    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

So there's nothing to restore, sorry.

Comment: Sadly you are right. This is because Windows isn't able to read ext, swap, btrfs,... partitions and thus formats them in the installation progress.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm on which partition is suppose to be installed your linux OS.
Both sda2 and sda3 appear to be NTFS. Ubuntu need to be on a ext4 (or ext2 / ext3).

Try to boot from live CD and see if in any of the partition you can find your Ubuntu.
If not I would re-install Ubuntu. This should sort your boot loader as well..